# Felix 4.4.0 Web Console Configurations

Tags: apache-felix

**Felix Web Console -> Configurations doesn't work.**

I've started Apache Felix 4.4.0 with bundles:

```
org.apache.felix.eventadmin-1.3.2.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
osgi.cmpn-4.2.jar
org.apache.felix.http.bundle-2.2.2.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.2.6.jar
org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.8.0.jar
org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.2.2-all.jar
```

My problems:

1. Web Console starts but when I select 'Status -> Configurations' I get: 'Status: No Configurations available'.
2. 'OSGi -> Configuration' view doesn't work.

I get the same with: `g! deploy org.apache.felix.webconsole.`

Thanks for help

zibi